# Dictionaries: Return a list of the keys which are paired with that value

Tags: javascript

I'm defining a function that returns a list of the keys which are paired with that value in the dictionary.

I can get the first key to be printed, but it will not print the second one or beyond. I know I should put in a list but I can't figure out to get that working.

```js
dict1 = {'cat' : 1, 'dog': 3, 'bird':4,'lizard':4,'hamster': 5 };

function keyList(dict, value) {

  for(x in dict)  

    if(dict[x] == value) 

    return x;
}

console.log(keyList(dict1, 4));
```

When I run the current program I just get bird.
I want the code to return both bird and lizard.

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate through the keys and filter the ones out where its value doesn't equal your passed value.

```js
dict1 = {'cat' : 1, 'dog': 3, 'bird':4,'lizard':4,'hamster': 5 }
    
function keyList(dict, value) {    
    return Object.keys(dict).filter(x => dict[x] === value);
}
    
console.log(keyList(dict1, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of immediately returning, push the value to an array then return the array

```js
dict1 = {'cat' : 1, 'dog': 3, 'bird':4,'lizard':4,'hamster': 5 }

function keyList(dict, value) {
    let keys = [];
    for(x in dict)
    if(dict[x] == value){keys.push(x);}
    return keys;
}

console.log(keyList(dict1, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)  to get an object's keys as an array (e.g. `["cat", "dog", "bird", "lizard", "hamster"]`).

[`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) then allows you to specify which items to keep.

In your case, you want to keep *"Keys whose value is 4"*, hence `obj[key] === value`.

```js
const dict1 = {'cat' : 1, 'dog': 3, 'bird':4,'lizard':4,'hamster': 5 };
const keyList = (obj, value) => Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === value);

console.log( keyList(dict1,4) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something this.  There may be a filter function that does something similar:

dict1 = {'cat' : 1, 'dog': 3, 'bird':4,'lizard':4,'hamster': 5 }

```
function getPropertiesByValue(object, value) {

Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
  if (object[key] != value ) delete object[key];
});
return object;
}
alert(JSON.stringify(getPropertiesByValue(dict1, 4)));
```

Comment: The major note with this approach is that it's an impure function; it manipulates the object that you pass in.